# How can I initialize a derived class using its attributes and the base class constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

Starting from a base class, I want to create some derived classes, which differs from one another for the value of a number of data members. These different attributes are used in the BaseClass constructor to inizialize other data members. Below you can find a simplified example of what I mean;

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(int a, double b, int c, std::string d) {
        // Do stuff depending also on d
    }
    double f;  // Inizialized in the BaseClass constructor
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d) {};
    std::string d = "Hello";
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass2(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d) {};
    std::string d = "Goodbye";
};
```

However, I am surely doing something wrong, since I get
`warning: field 'd' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]`. What is the right way to implement this?

Comment: what do you want `d` to be when you construct a `DerivedClass1` by calling this constructor `DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d), d(d);` ? What do you expect `d(d)` to do ?

Comment: " I am surely doing something wrong" yes, and thats why the code alone is not sufficient to explain what you want to do. Please try to explain what should happen when you construct the objects. What is the expected outcome?

Comment: If `d` is a constant, as in your examples, why not simply call `BaseClass(a, b, c, "Goodbye")`? If it is not a constant, you have to initialize it before calling the base class constructor. Note that calling `d(d)` in the derived constructors does not make sense and probably is what causes this warning - you are trying to initialize `d` with the value of `d`, which at this time is not yet initialized and also does not make any sense, as I guess the expected outcome would be that `d = d` anyway.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I want each derived class to be inizialized by the constructor of the `BaseClass`, considering the fact that the member `d` is different.
@Carsten, `d` is constant. However, what I presented is just a MWE. In my real code I have different data members changing and most of them are not simply standard datatypes. I agree that `d(d)` is useless, but removing it does not change the issue of the warning (edited to reflect this).

Comment: And why not move `d` into `BaseClass`? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/313qoseaW)

Comment: What is d?  If it's a data member of the derived classes, it doesn't belong in the base class constructor.  If it's a data member of the base class, then it belongs in the base class constructor, but it should be declared as a data member there and not in the derived classes.

Comment: @user1806566 It's a member of the derived classes. It should only represent an input of the constructor for the base class (since the other members depend on it).

Comment: You can't pass in `d` to the BaseClass, because `d` gets constructed **after** the BaseClass gets constructed.

Comment: @CaG Why not move `d` into `BaseClass`? That seems like the most obvious place for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the base sub-object is the first thing that gets initialized.  That is, this:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c)
      : BaseClass(a, b, c, d)
    {};
    std::string d = "Hello";
};
```

Is essentially equivalent to this:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c)
      : BaseClass(a, b, c, d),
        d("Hello")
    {};
    std::string d;
};
```

`d` is passed to `BaseClass`'s constructor before it gets initialized by `DerivedClass1`'s constructor.

To work around this you could introduce another base class that holds the extra member:

```
class DerivedBase {
public:
    DerivedBase(std::string d) : d(d) {}
    std::string d;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public DerivedBase, public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c)
      : DerivedBase("Hello"),
        BaseClass(a, b, c, d)
    {}
};
```

Since base classes are initialized in the order they're listed in the base-clause of the class declaration, `DerivedBase` will be initialized before `BaseClass`, so `d` will have been initialized before it gets passed to `BaseClass`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during derived class construction, the base class constructor runs before the derived class members are initialized.  That's why the compiler complains that `d` is uninitialized when you call the base class constructor with `d` as an argument.

If we leave your declarations as-is, I think you need to repeat yourself to get what you want.

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
  DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, "Hello") {};
  std::string d = "Hello";
};
```

Of course, repeating yourself isn't a good thing, but avoiding it would mean refactoring your code.  `d` is clearly a `BaseClass` concept (or it wouldn't need it in its constructor).  If you moved the data member to `BaseClass`, then the initialization order issue would be moot.

Comment: This is the same as @Miles Budnek's answer.  We must have been writing our answers at the same time...

Answer (score -1):

In your given code, i think you missed a point here. in the code:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(int a, double b, int c, std::string d) {
        // Do stuff depending also on d
    }
    double f;  // Inizialized in the BaseClass constructor
};
```

you have set 4 values in the constructor for the base class.. namely  `int a, double b, int c, std::string d`
This means whenever you call the constructor of the base class, you are supposed to pass in 4 arguments whereas in this code:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d), d(d) {}
    std::string d = "Hello";
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass2(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d), d(d) {}
    std::string d = "Goodbye";
};
```

in this both class, you have been passing something like a `d(d)` which i dont know what is .
In other words, just remove the `d(d)`.

EDIT: i found you have missed something here as well:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d), d(d) {}
    std::string d = "Hello";
};
```

you placed the block of code: `std::string d="Hello";` outside the scope of the constructor. Make these changes:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(int a, double b, int c, std::string d) {
        // Do stuff depending also on d
    }
    double f;  // Inizialized in the BaseClass constructor
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass {
public:
 std::string d="Anything you want to initialize d to is here";
    DerivedClass1(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d) {
   //Constructor code
}
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass {
public:
 std::string d="Same here as well";
    DerivedClass2(int a, double b, int c) : BaseClass(a, b, c, d) {
    //Constructor code
}
};
```

and you're good to go. Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I edited the question to remove `d(d)`, since it was a mistake (See my comment under the question). However, this answer forsees that the derived classes have 4 inputs. I'd like to have only 3 inputs, since the string `d` is constant and hardcoded.

Comment: I made some changes in the code .. take a look at it